# ChartJs grouped bar charts with each group with independent sets

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

Using Chart.js v2.x, I have the following goal:

- horizontal or vertical bars
- bars grouped together
- independent and unique data sets for each item

Sample data set:

group/category  : item : metric

- service1 : method1 : 40
- service1 : method2 : 45
- service2 : method4 : 5
- service3 : method5 : 15
- service3 : method6 : 30
- service3 : method7 : 45

the samples say to implement this using 3 data sets, however they all appear to need to based on the `item` in the example for comparison purposes. In my case, the only thing i need to compare is the metric.

The question is, is this possible with Chart.js and if so, how?

[image: example chart]

Comment: can you provide a graphical visualization on how your chart might look like?

Comment: @moáois updated with sample image

Comment: ok, its possible.. you want it in ChartJS v1 or v2 (code may differ based on version)?

Comment: Version 2 please

Comment: @moáois i thought i saw a request for data in json format. I'm actually printing out the javascript from java, so it doesn't really matter